# Values stored via one method cannot properly used in the next method (C#)

Tags: c#, methods

I am currently learning C# as a beginner and have this idea of a simple program that checks how my data entry (name + score) are holding up against the current highscore. I wrote the following code for this:

```
using System;

namespace Hello_World
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Highscore =0 ;
        static string HighscoreName = "Nobody";
        static string Name;
        static int intScore;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player();
            Test();
            Console.Read();   
        }

        public static void Player()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
                string Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("What is your score?");
                string score = Console.ReadLine();
                int intScore = int.Parse(score);
            
            }
            
        public static void Test()
        {
            if (intScore > Highscore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your {0} is the highscore, {1}", intScore, Name);
                Highscore = intScore;
                HighscoreName = Name;
            }
            else 
             { 
              Console.WriteLine("The current highscore is {0} and is held by {1}", Highscore, HighscoreName);   
             }
        }
        }       
    }
```

My problem is that Name and intScore are not properly stored by Player() so that Test() can pick these values up in order to check whether the inserted values are higher or lower than the current highscore. Can anyone please tell me how to ammend my code so it is working as desired?

Comment: I can suggest you read more about the basics of the language.

Comment: Local variables such as `intScore` and `Name` are only visible within the method on which they're declared. You might want to use you global variables instead.

Comment: This `int intScore = int.Parse(score);` creates a new variable that is local scoped to your method. I assume you wanted to store the parsed result in the static scoped variable intScore. To do so, remove the `int`. The same seems to apply to `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Player method like this

> ```
> public static void Player()
> {
>   Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
>   Name = Console.ReadLine();
>   Console.WriteLine("What is your score?");
>   string score = Console.ReadLine();
>   intScore = int.Parse(score);
> }
> ```

What you did was creating two local variables and assigning values to them instead of assigning to variables of the class

Comment: Thanks a lot! I new there was something with local and static variables but I just did not know where to make my adjustments. Now I know where to look for in the future :)